# how to loop over a list of dataframes and change specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes. Each dataframe of the list has following format:

[image]

(screenshot from spyder)

On this list of dataframes, I perform several tasks. For example, I want to change the name of "specA" to "Homo sapiens" in all of the dataframes, so I do the following:

```
for i,df in enumerate(dataframes_list):
    dataframes_list[i]=df.replace("specA","Homo sapiens")
```

This gives me the desired output.

I perform several other of these kind of `for loops` with the same structure, i.e.:

```
for i,df in enumerate(dataframes_list):
    dataframes_list[i]= *expression*
```

In the end, for each dataframe I sum the "reads" column of all species:

```
for i,df in enumerate(dataframes_list):
    dataframes_list[i]=(df.groupby('species')['reads'].sum()).to_frame()
```

and thereafter merge all dataframes in the list to a single dataframe:

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['species'],
                                            how='outer'), dataframes_list)
```

This gives me exactly the output I want to have.

Now there is a new task I want to perform, but I don't know how to implement it.

For each dataframe in the list, I want to change the "perc_ID" value of species "specC" to "100". This could be done with .loc:

```
df.loc[df.species == "specC","perc_ID"]=100
```

But I need to loop over de DFs in the list so that would be:

```
for i,df in enumerate(dataframes_list):
  dataframes_list[i]=df.loc[df.species == "specC","perc_ID"]=100
```

this obviously does not work, as in the second line, there is 2x "=".

I could change this by removing `enumerate`:

```
for df in dataframes_list:
  df.loc[df.species == "specC","perc_ID"]=100
```

this works. However, as I mentioned, i perform several of these `for loops`, including `enumerate`. For some reason, if I remove the `enumerate` in combination with `dataframes_list[i]` for all for loops, my merging of the dataframes gets messed up. Therefore I would like to keep the `enumerate` and `dataframes_list[i]` for all my `for loops`.

So my question: How can I change the value of a specific column, based on the value of another column, when looping over a list of dataframes?

So, how to write the following code, but keeping `enumerate` and `dataframes_list[i]`?

```
for i,df in enumerate(dataframes_list):
  dataframes_list[i]=df.loc[df.species == "specC","perc_ID"]=100
```

Thanks!

**PS: there are likely way better methods to work with this kind of data (no for loops, no dataframe lists,..) However, I'm not a Python expert, and I understand what I write in this way. Therefore I like to keep this structure.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this:

If I understand correctly, the `df` is on each iteration of the loop going to point to a different dataframe, so this should result in what you want.

```
for df in dataframes_list:
  df.loc[df.species == "specC","perc_ID"]=100
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I was not completely clear. I wanted to keep ```enumerate``` in combination with ```dataframes_list[i]```. It should also work without, but for some reason something goes wrong downstream.

Comment: I tried your way and it works. It also works without ```i``` and ```enumerate```. Anyway, the way you write it works, so accepted as solution.

Comment: Yes absolutely you do not need the `i` and `enumerate`. I have removed them.

Comment: it still remains weird that if I delete all ```i``` and ```enumerate``` from all my for loops, merging is completely messed up..

Comment: It's not weird: without the `enumerate`, and just using `df = ...`,  you are no longer writing to the parent list: you are just reassigning the loop variable `df`. That doesn't affect the parent list.

Comment: However, why is this not the case for your solution? I just posted a new question about this cause I don't understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648845/why-does-loc-change-values-in-place-while-dfdf-col-expression-does-not

Comment: I now found out due to an answer on another post that an operation behaves differently than an indexer like ```.loc```. All clear now, thanks for your help!